# Form submission in Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have this problem where after I submitted a form then I performed "F5" or "refresh"
there still data that were submitted, every time I press "F5" same data as the first time I submitted the form, then it became duplicate entry, I tried clearing the POST data as well as the field_data in CI, still there is still the values being submitted, I don't know why it can't be trapped on `form_validation`, where I set a rule that is required.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment','Comment','required');

if(/*form validation is false*/) //fail
{
   // some code for incorrect values
}
else //success
{
   $_POST = array();
   $this->form_validation->clear_field_data();
  //and some code for views
}
```

Now, on a normal process, it has no errors, but when on SUCCESS and I pressed "F5" or refreshed the page, the data gets submitted again thus inserting it again to the DB, 
I really don't know why it happen already cleared everything from field data to actual post data, If you have any knowledge please do share

BTW just a headsup, my `form_validation` is a custom made one, extends the CI's native form_validation

Comment: Could it possibly be the browser caching it?

Comment: hmmm maybe but i don't know how to view the cache.. can't view it through the CI profiler? any idea how to view it or better clear it? in CI

Comment: You clear your browser cache from within your browser. If that fixes the issue temporarily it means the browser is indeed caching the form submittal and you will need to set the proper HTTP headers to prevent it.

Comment: hmmm i know how dat works, but i don't think users will know clearing the cache will solve this, i mean by clearing it programatically so as to prevent from re-submitting it

Comment: If the form validation is successful then using a `redirect` is a common way to stop form resubmission (rather than loading views, for example).

Comment: one more thing dont let duplicate entry happen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `redirect` function insteed of `$this->load->view`

you can see it [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: using rederict is much more easier and i think more efficient, for success messgaes just use the flash data, anyways it'll be destroyed at the next server request

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use redirect (preferabl) or use a server side header to not store the post data:

```
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header ("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
{
   $data['Name']['value'] = $this->input->post('name', TRUE);
   $this->load->view("someview",$data);
}
else
{
   $data['Name']['value'] = "";
   $this->load->view("someview",$data);

}
```